# Map View - Current Location after moving the map view

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview

Loaded Map view on the screen.

If we move the map from left and right

i need to get the current location on the screen immediatly when i click a button

i used the following code to get the current location initially

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation{
    MKCoordinateRegion region =    MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 800, 800);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];

    // Add an annotation
    MKPointAnnotation *point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate;
    point.title = @"Where am I?";
    point.subtitle = @"I'm here!!!";

    [self.mapView addAnnotation:point];
}
```

Comment: whats your question now..?

Comment: After moving from one location to another i have to come to current location by clicking the button

Comment: for this location point.coordinate = userLocation.coordinate; correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by clicking the button call below method.

```
  - (void)gotoLocation
    {
        float spanX = 0.05;
        float spanY = 0.05;
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center.latitude = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
        region.center.longitude = mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        region.span.latitudeDelta = spanX;
        region.span.longitudeDelta = spanY;
        [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
```